# in Helm 3 how to get the entire mapped yaml from values file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to get the following "Match" values from the values.yaml file

```
PublicVirtualService:
match:
  - uri:  
      prefix: "/api/webhook/"
  - method:
      exact: POST
```

and this is the helm template file I am trying with

```
 http:
  {{- if hasKey .Values.PublicVirtualService "match" }}
  - match:  
      {{- toJson $.Values.PublicVirtualService.match | indent 2 }}
  {{- end }}
```

so the final rendered output will be going to looks like this

```
  http:
  - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: "/api/hook/"
      - method:
          exact: POST
```

But it's looking like this after running the debug

```
     http:
     - match:  [{"uri":{"prefix":"/api/hook/"}},{"method":{"exact":"POST"}}]
```

So far I have tried different methods but without any success . Any way to get all the values that's are under the "match" as it is in values yaml file .

Also tried with toYaml

but it's looking like this

```
http:
- match:  "- uri:  \n    prefix: \"/api/webhook/\"\n- method:\n    exact: POST\n"
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/

Comment: Well, you're calling `toJson` so it's rendering as JSON; it sounds like you want `toYaml $.Values...`

Comment: I have tried with the yaml too .
`
match: |
  - uri:  
      prefix: "/api/webhook/"
  - method:
      exact: POST
`

and getting it rendered like this

`
 http:
 - match:  "- uri:  \n    prefix: \"/api/webhook/\"\n- method:\n    exact: POST\n"
`

Comment: `helm template --output-dir './' './'` you can use this command where `./` are paths. Is that what you are looking for? [Here](https://scriptcrunch.com/convert-helm-chart-kubernetes-yaml/) is an article which could be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Your initial output is correct and you don't need to do anything.

One of the interesting design points of YAML is that all valid JSON is supposed to be valid YAML.  The same syntactic constructs exists: `[...]` is an inline way to write a list, `{key: value}` is an object, you're allowed to quote any string.  So your one-line output of `toJson` is valid YAML, and has the same structure as the input.

If you want it to be in multi-line YAML form, Helm includes a `toYaml` function that can produce that.  Indentation is important and the default output of `toYaml` is indented starting at the first column, so you'll usually need to combine this with the `indent` helper.  This should work:

```yaml
http:
{{- with .Values.PublicVirtualService.match }}
  - http:
{{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

One important difference between this and your original form is that there is not a `-` before `toYaml` (or `toJson`).  This consumes all of the whitespace before the markup, which includes the newline, so the child markup is on the same line as the tag.  That's fine for the one-line JSON form but doesn't work for multi-line YAML.

I've also used a shorter `with...end` block here.  `with` acts like `if`, but binds the special variable `.` to its condition if it's truthy.  `$any_map.key` is defined but `nil` if `key` isn't defined, which is falsey.  If `...match` is defined (and non-empty) then the `with` block executes, and then `{{ toYaml . }}` serializes the condition's value.  Note that this use of `.` conflicts with the default Helm use of constructs like `.Values`.